# Caching results in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, caching, stored-procedures

1. I have a stored procedure with 20-30 optional parameters.
2. There are inline TVF's corresponding to these parameters which are called when parameters passed to the stored procedure.
3. There is a common dbo.Match function called by these TVF's that looks up for String Matches in `Table A` and does fair amount of calculations computes percent match which is inserted into field `Percent` of Table returned by Inline TVF.
4. The stored procedure in the end inserts all parameters passed to it with their Percent Match results into a table called `dbo.Results`

Note: In results table, I am not storing percent match of every value passed as parameter but average of all the parameters that were passed in a run.But In the end , Each of those parameters is a string and needs to be matched separately and this is being done in `dbo.Match` table . I had thought I would directly store the PercentMatch result of every parameter value from dbo.Match table  and store in a table which I will treat as cache but I can not do it here as dbo.Match is function so Insert statement not allowed here. How do I go about it ?

However, same value to those parameters may be passed into stored procedure over the life time of application and I do not want them to be looked up in database everytime and make all the calculations repeatedy. So, I am looking for something that can possible `cache` the results. I need to Retrieve the results from cache only if data has not changed (which can be done with timestamps so is not a problem to check).

How exactly do I need to proceed in order to have favorable performance by caching already looked up strings?

Comment: Can't you just save the dbo.Results table for each of the search words and in case something is changed, delete all records related to any of the searches that might be affected. So you can first look up the cached results, and if not found, then do the normal search.

Comment: Store things in a table with a timestamp. Check against this timestamp somehow. If the results haven't expired, return them. As written, your question is too broad. Have you tried anything? Also, have you possibly considered doing the caching on the client end, rather than the server end, which makes more sense? Saves a possibly big data roundtrip, after all.

Comment: @JamesZ: Please check the edit. I can not do that. A row in Results table has Average match of all the parameters that were passed in a run and not of every parameter of  a run.To save time and improve efficiency, I am avoiding looking up for those  parameter values that have already been looked at.

Comment: @JeroenMostert:We have this constraint that we can do none of it at client side. Please check the Note that I added in my question. That is exactly where I am stuck.

Comment: Can you change the Match function into a procedure? This is quite broad topic and without any detail info it's quite impossible to give any suggestions.

Comment: @JamesZ: No, because as I have mentioned above, dbo.Match is being called from TVF's and as far as I know, stored procedures can not be called from TVF's.? If there is an alternative to go about it, I will be happy to do that.

Comment: @JamesZ: I understand that I may not have included all the details in question but having an idea of approach probably will do for me :) . But please let me know if I have missed upon any important details in my question. Any direction to proceed with it will be helpful .Thanks